# XCode 6.3 Alamofire.swift file crashed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, serialization, xcode6.3

I'm new in swift. I use Alamofire in my project. Also, I installed XCode 6.3. Then, Alamofire.swift file crashed. I fixed all errors, but I could not fix the code below in Alamofire.swift file:

```
public func response(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(Request.responseDataSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

It says that **missing argument for parameter 'serializer' in call**.

How can I fix it ?

Thank you for your answers,

Best regards

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/344. See this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should currently use the Alamofire Xcode 6.3 branch:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/xcode-6.3

Because IOS 8.3 is out now, I guess they will merge it soon into the main branch.

Comment: I solved it by applying your recommandation thank you @Prine :)

Answer (score 6):

Just FYI, [Alamofire 1.2.0](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases/tag/1.2.0) was released this morning which fully supports Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3. You no longer need to use the `xcode-6.3` branch. That will certainly resolve your **missing argument for parameter 'serializer' in call** issue.

Comment: I have integrated the "Alamofire 1.2.0 " as matt has mentioned but I am not able to run the app because it is giving me two errors. I have contacted you on Github too but I didn't receive any answer. Will you please let me know what is the issue with this?  have posted my question on Stackoverflow as well. -------------------
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791424/errors-with-alamafire-sdk-with-xcode-6-3-and-ios-8-3"

Comment: That link is dead dude. If you get it fixed, I'll certainly take a look. I'm always glad to help when and where I can.

Comment: @matt I have received your response on GitHub and i didn't mean that I don't have respect for your work! You did an awesome work. All I wanted is some help as I was stuck there since week. Since you have locked the Commenting on that issue, hence posting here! I hope you will receive this.

Comment: I want to say to you as well that please don't take my words in another way. I am very thankful to you for your work.

Comment: again that problem is coming to me. Please check! Link is working now

Answer (score 2):

Replace with this method :-

```
 public func response(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(serializer: Request.responseDataSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)

    }
```

[more Detail then click here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift)