# Errors with Alamafire SDK with XCode 6.3 and iOS 8.3

Tags: frameworks, alamofire, xcode6.3, ios8.3

Anyone please let me know what is this all about? I am stuck since a week on this and no help from searching. I posted my query to the developer of Alamofire but still no response. Please help! I am totally confused what is wrong in the integration of Alamofire. I have followed every step and this issue is coming with XCode 6.3 as before it was running properly.

[image]

When I am adding the Framework under "Copy Frameworks", it is adding the Framework twice showing different paths but when I am Going to there location, it is taking me to the same location. Here is the screen shot.

[image]

I have also created the video for that issue. May be that can help in a better way. Please see [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1kxn589r3vnwi5/Alamofire%20Issue.mov?dl=0)

Moreover, latest SDK contains framework for MAC OS as well but I didn't add that. I hope all the above information will help you in helping me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you explain me how have you integrate Alamofire? via cocoapods, sources, ...?

Comment: We'd be glad to help, but without more details it will be impossible to narrow down. I'm assuming you aren't using Carthage or CocoaPods. If you were, you most likely wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: @Masterfego : I have manually added the framework as I did earlierand it was working perfectly. Ever since I havce updated my XCode to 6.3 version, I am facing this issue with Latest SDK.

Comment: @cnoon I haven't used Cocoapods or Carthage as I have little knowledge about that but I am sure I have followed the correct way of manually adding the Framework as I did earlier too before the current version.

Comment: Ok I understand, have you update Alamofire? With the arrival of xcode 6.3, developper have to update their frameworks to be compatible with swift 1.2,  I use the lastest version: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases/tag/1.2.1. But the best way is to use cocoapods, it's very easy and you will never care about framework integration

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be incredibly difficult to debug without a sample project that is set up in the same manner as your actual one. If you had imported Alamofire project into your project, you wouldn't see two versions of Alamofire appear when you add it to the `Copy Frameworks` build phase. If you truly want to resolve this quickly, you have two options.

#### Option 1

Push up a sample project to Github and link it here. We can then take a look at the project and pretty quickly access what the issue is. The main reason it's so difficult here is that there are roughly 10 different things that could be the cause of the issue. Therefore, it's much faster for you to create a sample project than for us to go round-and-round (which we've already started with @Masterfego).

#### Option 2

Take the leap and try out [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html). It is a fantastic dependency management system that will forever alleviate these annoying types of project management issues. CocoaPods itself has fantastic documentation. Also, the Alamofire [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#cocoapods) breaks down in detail how to add Alamofire to your project using CocoaPods.

---

#### Recommendation

I would highly encourage you to choose `Option 2`. That is definitely the fastest way forward and you won't regret moving to a more robust dependency management system. It makes managing library updates and new installations extremely simple.

If you do end up going with `Option 1`, then I'll take a look at your sample project and revise my answer.